# Lubuntu or Ubuntu

Tags: syslinux

I want to ask: I have laptop with Intel Pentium M with single core, RAM 1 GB, HDD 30 GB. What is the best Linux software for my computer?

Comment: Where could we download it? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu should make the suitable choice for you, knowing that you have an low memory system. It is based on the LXDE environment which aims to be lightweight, it runs fast and takes up less resources than any other Ubuntu flavor (CMIIW).

Reportedly Lubuntu can work speedily on even 128 MB of RAM, so with 1GB ram of yours, there shouldn't be any problem working with this flavor.

You can find tutorial to install Lubuntu here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu